# Executing queries from sqlite file in iOS

Tags: ios, database, file, sqlite, database-scripts

Is it possible to read a `.sqlite` script with row insertions and updates in iOS? Or if you want to read `sql` statements from a file, you can only read the file line by line as if it were a regular text file? I need to make a large amount of row insertions in an already existing `sqlite` table I have, and I have all the `insert` statements in an `.sql` file. I've looking for a way to do this, but I was not able to find any for iOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your .sqlite script is just a text file so you can load it. You can read it in line by line but you can also read the whole script (depending on size) into an `NSString` (`stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`) and then use the contents however you want.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where can I find an example of executing the `NSString` I get, assuming that it contains `sql` statements?

Comment: I have the statements in code as `const char*` and I use the `sqlite_prepare_v2` function with such `const char*` and a `sqlite3 stmt`. Should I read the lines of the file and supply them to the `sqlite_prepare_v2` function one by one, or is there any way to just run the whole script?